# Central-mode of slick-slider

Tags: javascript, slider, slick.js

I need slider on web-page  and i get slick-slider. I wanted use slider center-mode but a little change this slider. I would that central element of that slider had bigger size than  other elements of the slider.
But i can't to detetmine what class use central element, i try applied class "slick-center", "slick-current" but this attempts  don't work.
This is my problem

```js
$('.slidy').slick({
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '10px',
            slidesToShow: 3,
        responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
            arrows: true,
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '40px',
            slidesToShow: 3
        }
        },
        {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '40px',
            slidesToShow: 1
        }}
            ]
        });
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    var next = document.querySelector('.slick-next');
    next.onclick = function() {
      
      document.querySelector('.slick-center').style.border ="2px solid red";
      document.querySelector('.slick-center').style.transform="scale(1.2, 1.2)"
    }
  }
)
```

```css
.slick-prev:after {
  content: ">";
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.slick-next:before {
  content: "<";
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.7/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.js"></script>
<div class="slidy">
  <div> peace of one </div>
  <div> peace of two </div>
  <div> peace of tree </div>
  <div> peace of four </div>
  <div> peace of five </div>
  <div> peace of six </div>
</div>
```

If you advise how write sliders by himself it will be cool)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.slidy').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: "35px",
  speed: 500
});
```

Your can add padding with `centerPadding : "";` option also
you can apply your own CSS for center one this way:

```
.slidy .slick-center{}
```